# How can I multiply a vector by a scaling value with a loop in matlab?

Tags: matlab, loops, scale, multiplication

Hi I have a vector A (1x200) and I want to multiply it for a scaling factor of 0.2 for 10 times. I would like to obtain a matrix B(10x200) where each row is the scaled vector?

thanks

Comment: If that's what you want to do, then I say do it. Don't let anyone try to stop you.

Comment: Please read [ask], being explicit about your question, and showing what you attempted, will help you get good answers here.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the first row of B to be A scaled by a factor of 0.2 and then the second row of B to be A scaled by a factor of 0.2^2 and so on, write:

```
 for i=1:10
    B(i,:)= A*0.2^i
 end
```

If you want to write A*0.2 ten times, then write:

```
  for i=1:10
     B(i,:)=0.2*A  
  end
```